# Why can't we have more than 3 moment equations in equilibrium equations

Tags: torque, statics, moment

Excuse me for a kind of stupid question but,

In statics of a 3D rigid body, the equations to determine equilibrium are at most 6 (Fx Fy Fz Mx My Mz = 0) (not counting those from hinges and rollers).

So i was wondering why we cant calculate moment about a lot of points and axes and have loads of equations.
I tried to do it but the equations were not independent and my efforts turned useless.

So i know it's not correct but i can't find the explanations anyway

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Forces and torques (or moments) are *vectors*. In a nice coordinate system, like the mutually perpendicular x,y,z axes we usually use, all possible forces and torques can be represented as a combination of forces or torques along the coordinate axes. This, basically, is why we use a specific coordinate system with basis vectors.

For example, any torque along the x-y plane can be represented as a combination of torques along the x and y axes.